# How to take screenshot of a div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building something called the "HTML Quiz". It's completely ran on JavaScript and it's pretty cool.

At the end, a results box pops up that says "Your Results:" and it shows how much time they took, what percentage they got, and how many questions they got right out of 10. I would like to have a button that says "Capture results" and have it somehow take a screenshot or something of the div, and then just show the image captured on the page where they can right click and "Save image as."

I really would love to do this so they can share their results with others. I don't want them to "copy" the results because they can easily change that. If they change what it says in the image, oh well.

Does anyone know a way to do this or something similar?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.phantomjs.org/ . Using it you could generate a full image of the HTML page on the serverside, and give the user a link to download.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image

Answer (score 130, accepted):

No, I don't know of a way to 'screenshot' an element, but what you could do, is draw the quiz results into a canvas element, then use the `HTMLCanvasElement` object's `toDataURL` function to get a `data:` URI with the image's contents.

When the quiz is finished, do this:

```
var c = document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
/* then use the canvas 2D drawing functions to add text, etc. for the result */
```

When the user clicks "Capture", do this:

```
window.open('', document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id').toDataURL());
```

This will open a new tab or window with the 'screenshot', allowing the user to save it. There is no way to invoke a 'save as' dialog of sorts, so this is the best you can do in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know anything about canvas, but I will learn it. How would I use the Canvas 2D drawing effects? Could you assist me with this? Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Try Mozilla's documentation, it's really quite easy to follow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

Comment: Instead of opening it in a new window/tab, can I open it in a inline dialog box? (Like the Fancybox lightbox plugin?)

Comment: Yep, you can have an inline dialog box with an `img` that has its `src` set to the `data:` URI. However, that isn't really necessary -- you can just put the `canvas` itself in the inline dialog box; users can right click it and save the current state as an image.

Comment: Thanks :) I might use the image version so they will be able to right click and click "save image as"

Comment: No, what I'm saying is, that `canvas` elements function exactly like `img` elements in that you can right click and save them.

Comment: Seems to be better to send data to server and return as downloadable file to user

Comment: What's the meaning of "t" in Delan Azabani's code? I suppose c is for canvas.

Comment: HTML5 Canvas has "Save Image..." with right click, too.

Comment: The link to the canvas tutorial has changed:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial

Answer (score 125):

This is an expansion of @Dathan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887750/189134), using [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;


                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This code block waits for the button with the id `btnSave` to be clicked. When it is, it converts the `widget` div to a canvas element and then uses the saveAs() FileSaver interface (via FileSaver.js in browsers that don't support it natively) to save the div as an image named "Dashboard.png".

An example of this working is available at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FZkk/1/).

Comment: I needed to add references to: html2canvas, filesaver, blob, canvas-toBlob.  After that it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, this should be the accepted answer. Straightforward plug n play.

Comment: Do you know how this would work with three.js? I have a div that the three.js renderer / canvas is in (renderer.domElement), and then divs on top of that. I'd like to take a snapshot of the parent DIV and capture everything? Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Can you avoid image appearing in your DOM? Can't it just go to download straight away?

Comment: The fiddle does not do anything!

Comment: html2canvas does not support direction style.

Comment: This worked great for me on the first try, and even looks like the original CSS styling etc.  Amazingly accurate.  Pretty much a virtual screen-shot with this level of accuracy.  I used CDN for the 2 libraries I had to add:    <!-- html2canvas -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  
  <!-- filesaver -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.2/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

Comment: Without JQuery or FileSaver, put this in you function:
```html2canvas(document.querySelector('#my-div')).then(canvas => {
  window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0), '_blank');
});```

Comment: I tried the fiddle but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this save images too? I tried on the fiddle but it doesn't work. Perhaps they need to be in 'same origin' ?

Comment: The fiddle seems to have a broken reference to filesaver.js

Comment: For those of you who said the fiddle doesn't work. Just delete the current script and add the new ones. Watch out for the proper version - `0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js` and `2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js`. Get it from here `https://cdnjs.com/`

Comment: A lots of CSS Property doesn't work in HTML2Canvas.

Answer (score 28):

After hours of research, I finally found a solution to take a screenshot of an element, even if the `origin-clean` FLAG is set (to prevent XSS), that´s why you can even capture for example Google Maps (in my case). I wrote a universal function to get a screenshot. The only thing you need in addition is the html2canvas library (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

**Example:**

```
getScreenshotOfElement($("div#toBeCaptured").get(0), 0, 0, 100, 100, function(data) {
    // in the data variable there is the base64 image
    // exmaple for displaying the image in an <img>
    $("img#captured").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,"+data);
});
```

Keep in mind `console.log()` and `alert()` won´t generate output if the size of the image is great.

**Function:**

```
function getScreenshotOfElement(element, posX, posY, width, height, callback) {
    html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var imageData = context.getImageData(posX, posY, width, height).data;
            var outputCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var outputContext = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');
            outputCanvas.width = width;
            outputCanvas.height = height;

            var idata = outputContext.createImageData(width, height);
            idata.data.set(imageData);
            outputContext.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);
            callback(outputCanvas.toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
        },
        width: width,
        height: height,
        useCORS: true,
        taintTest: false,
        allowTaint: false
    });
}
```

Comment: where you have defined html2canvas function

Comment: I integrated the library html2canvas (see link in my post) before the function getScreenshotOfElement() is reached. For example with the <script>-tag. Just download html2canvas and copy it to your project.

Comment: @orange01 - I am still not able to capture street lanes of google map. This only screenshot the zoom In and out button, Map and satellite text.
can you please help to capture full map.
Thanks

Comment: FYI, the syntax has changed since this was posted. "onrendered" is no longer a property and the function should be moved to a "then" call: `html2canvas(element, { width, height, ...}).then(function (canvas) { ... })`

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to have "Save as" dialog, just pass image into php script, which adds appropriate headers

Example "all-in-one" script `script.php`

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['image'])):
    $image = $_GET['image'];

    if(preg_match('#^data:image/(.*);base64,(.*)$#s', $image, $match)){
        $base64 = $match[2];
        $imageBody = base64_decode($base64);
        $imageFormat = $match[1];

        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false); // required for certain browsers
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.".$imageFormat."\";" ); //png is default for toDataURL
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".strlen($imageBody));
        echo $imageBody;
    }
    exit();
endif;?>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="btn">Save</button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var oCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        oCtx.beginPath();
        oCtx.moveTo(0,0);
        oCtx.lineTo(300,150);
        oCtx.stroke();

        $('#btn').on('click', function(){
            // opens dialog but location doesnt change due to SaveAs Dialog
            document.location.href = '/script.php?image=' + canvas.toDataURL();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

> Add this Script in your index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
```

> Use this function to get screenshot of div tag

```
  getScreenShot(){
    let c = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.chartContainer'); // or document.getElementById('canvas');
    html2canvas(c).then((canvas:any)=>{
      var t = canvas.toDataURL().replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
      this.downloadBase64File('image/png',t,'image');
    })
  }

downloadBase64File(contentType:any, base64Data:any, fileName:any) {
  const linkSource = `data:${contentType};base64,${base64Data}`;
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = linkSource;
  downloadLink.download = fileName;
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have any resource how this can be opened in camera roll or google photos please? Need image to be shared on social media.

Answer (score 4):

You can't take a screen-shot: it would be an irresponsible security risk to let you do so. However, you can:

- Do things server-side and generate an image
- Draw something similar to a Canvas and render that to an image (in a browser that supports it)
- Use some other drawing library to draw directly to the image (slow, but would work on any browser)

Comment: Thanks! I will go with the canvas, as I don't know of any "drawing libraries" nor do I know how to do that. I'm not that good at canvas either but I'll try.

Comment: Sorry i have to comment this as it comes from google but WTF "irresponsible security risk" might i ask why, if you let javascript take a screenshot or a shot within given cords and return the BASE64 encoded data of it as a string no Security problem

Comment: @MartinBarker I could (for example) pull up someone's Facebook page in an iframe and then screenshot it. Normally a cross-site iframe isn't part of the accessible DOM to prevent XSS, but it would be much harder for the browser vendor to stop it in this such case.

Comment: whats wrong with that there not going to see any thing still the same as it currently is if a user was to Print screen the browser with facebook in it

Comment: @MartinBarker The Javascript could give the data to a malicious source without the user even noticing, whereas "print screen" is controlled by the user, and not some some arbitrary untrusted website.

Comment: What a beat up. @PiPeep, If a webpage can load up an iFrame of Facebook, there is already isolation, why not extend such isolation with a screenshot API? eg. Div.ToPNG(), where the aforementioned iFrame is whited out? It's not an irresponsible security risk, it just not there built-in and no one has worked through "potential" privacy/security issues in developing such a built in screenshot API. It would be immensely useful for a myriad of use-cases, such as support of intranet web applications for example.

Comment: I know this is old, but it's not currently possible to take a screenshot of a cross-site iframe using javascript. Perhaps it was possible back in the day though...

Answer (score 4):

```
var shot1=imagify($('#widget')[0], (base64) => {
  $('img.screenshot').attr('src', base64);
});
```

Take a look at [htmlshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlshot) package , then, check  deeply the **client side** section:

```
npm install htmlshot
```

Comment: is this htmlshot project still maintained?  The github link from npm doesn't look to still exist. Is there another website for it?

Comment: @whatsTheDiff: : give me your requirements , and , be sure that i will help you .since i am the author of this library.

Comment: Thanks @abdennour-toumi.  I just did an npm install to look through the code.  Looks like it's using html2canvas which I've tried and am having issues with in IE and due to the SVG's and complexity of my page.  So appears that this library won't help me in that regards.

Comment: Your customer has to avoid IE.. tell them that!

Answer (score 4):

```
<script src="/assets/backend/js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $("#download").on('click', function(){
        html2canvas($("#printform"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var url = canvas.toDataURL();

                var triggerDownload = $("<a>").attr("href", url).attr("download", getNowFormatDate()+"电子签名详细信息.jpeg").appendTo("body");
                triggerDownload[0].click();
                triggerDownload.remove();
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

[quotation](http://www.cnblogs.com/yanweidie/p/5203943.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's to simple you can use this code for capture the screenshot of particular area 
you have to define the div id in html2canvas. I'm using here 2 div-:
div id="car"
div id ="chartContainer"
if you want to capture only cars then use **car** i'm capture here car only you can change **chartContainer** for capture the graph
**html2canvas($('#car')**
copy and paste this code

```html
<html>
    <head>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
    
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "light2",
        title:{
            text: "Simple Line Chart"
        },
        axisY:{
            includeZero: false
        },
        data: [{        
            type: "line",       
            dataPoints: [
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 414},
                { y: 520, indexLabel: "highest",markerColor: "red", markerType: "triangle" },
                { y: 460 },
                { y: 450 },
                { y: 500 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 410 , indexLabel: "lowest",markerColor: "DarkSlateGrey", markerType: "cross" },
                { y: 500 },
                { y: 480 },
                { y: 510 }

            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
    
    }
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black">
<div id="wholebody">  
<a href="javascript:genScreenshotgraph()"><button style="background:aqua; cursor:pointer">Get Screenshot of Cars onl </button> </a>

<div id="car" align="center">
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:70px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:50px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:20px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:50px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:60px;color:red;"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-car" style="font-size:70px;color:red;"></i>
</div>
<br>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<div id="box1">
</div>
</div>>
</body>

<script>

function genScreenshotgraph() 
{
    html2canvas($('#car'), {
        
      onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        var pdf = new jsPDF();
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, -180, -180);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
        
      
      
      }
     });

}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Why is jQuery included twice, and why is jQuery UI included? Honestly, jQuery is not needed here at all from what I can tell. `document.getElementById('car')` or `document.querySelector('#car')`

Comment: actually i'm working on my project. so i just forget about to remove the library and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your html file and `id="capture"` to the div you want to take screenshot

```html
<a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
<script src="capture.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In `capture.js` add:

```js
document.getElementById("btn-Convert-Html2Image").addEventListener("click", function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("capture")).then(function (canvas) {
    var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
    anchorTag.download = "filename.jpg";
    anchorTag.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    anchorTag.target = '_blank';
    anchorTag.click();
  });
});
```

Then, just press download and it will download the screenshot

Or you can view screenshot img by add

```html
<div id="previewImg"></div>
```

in html code is where you want to view that img and js code will be

```js
document.getElementById("btn-Convert-Html2Image").addEventListener("click", function() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById("capture")).then(function (canvas) {
    var anchorTag = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(anchorTag);
    document.getElementById("previewImg").appendChild(canvas);
    anchorTag.click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do that, I may be wrong. However I'd do this with php, generate a JPEG using php standard functions and then display the image, should not be a very hard job, however depends on how flashy the contents of the DIV are

Comment: The OP never suggested that he is using server-side processing, though if he was, this would be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use server-side stuff unfortunately. I will probably go with one of the answers above. But thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

first you need include [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/):

##### HTML

```
<div id="toBeCaptured">
<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>
</div>
<img id="captured" src="">
```

##### Javascript

```
async function x(){
  const data = await    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#toBeCaptured"));
  document.querySelector("#captured").src = data.toDataURL();
  document.innerHTML = data.toDataURL();
}
x();
```

Answer (score -7):

**This is an ~11 year old answer. Please ignore this answer and check other recent answers here**

As far as I know its not possible with javascript.

What you can do for every result create a screenshot, save it somewhere and point the user when clicked on save result. (I guess no of result is only 10 so not a big deal to create 10 jpeg image of results)

Comment: Thanks for answering :) You're right! I could just create 10 JPG images of the results and then once they click the button, it'll show the image for them to save. The only problem is that when they start the quiz, they have to enter their name, and I display it through out the quiz, and at the end in the results box, it shows their name and it says a comment like "Getting Better" etc. I wouldn't be able to put the name of them in the image or would I?