# how can i take a screen shot and save it in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

how can i take a screen shot and save it in PHP? I wana take a screen shot a users screen and  save it to user's machine when he/she clicks on save button. Is there any way to do this??

Comment: If you searched for "screenshot php" on stackoverflow, you'd find hundreds of duplicates telling you it cannot be done.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php

Comment: `onclick="alert('Please press Print Screen Key on your keyboard.');"`

Comment: PHP is the wrong choice of a programming language for such a feature. Even if you'll find a way to capture and save a screenshot, you still need a webserver running on the clients PC. Try some other scripting language, e.g. Python…
@Leigh Well you can; see the other linked questions for different solutions; for example: http://www.os-cms.net/blog/view/5/how-to-create-a-screen-dump-with-php-on-linux

Comment: @Leigh — No, you'll find lots of people asking how to take a screenshot directly with PHP (and not on the visitor's computer) … as per the first and third comment.

Comment: @feeela — PHP is rarely used without a webserver, not *impossible* (or even hard) to use without one.

Comment: @Quentin: I find no information that puts the users computer in relatation to the servers computer, so how can you say, the user is not the programmer here creating that system?

Comment: @Quentin "[when the user] clicks on save button" How would you accomplish that? AFAIK PHP has no standalone GUI – just a CLI interface…

Comment: @Quentin: Exactly, and that's what this question is asking. Either that or it's badly written. It looks pretty clear from what is written that he wants to use PHP (the overwhelming majority of the time on the server) to take and save a screenshot on the clients machine. Nowhere does it state the client should have to download PHP, and run a script using ridiculous com objects to get a screenshot, etc. If your crystal ball enables you to know better than what the question is asking, feel free to improve the question.

Comment: @feeela - we're getting off topic, since it's not what the OP wants, but a standalone GUI library for PHP can be found here: http://php-gtk.eu/

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this in PHP.

You could do this using HTML5/Javascript, something like [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) does.

Your problem with that would be compatibility with older browsers. So using this would depend on who the website is aimed at.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand one thing that **PHP is a server side script** and nothing to do with real time browser needs. You may try **JavaScript** with some library like **jQuery** to capture the screenshot. Then you may pass that image via **AJAX** and there, you can definitely use PHP to save the image into your server directory.

***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)*** stackoverflow question may help you.