# Capturing screen image in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, screenshot

How to capture the active screen in `ASP.Net MVC`?

Is there any feature in JQuery for this?

What I am looking for is to save the specific part of screen (say a parent div content) on click of a button and show Print dialog to user which will print this as an image.

I found many posts around but I am looking for **MVC & JQuery** specific solution.

Can anybody please suggest?

Comment: What posts have you found? Maybe we could help you adapting them.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *screen capture* in a rendered page you might want to check out the HTML5 canvas element and capture what's drawn in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887206/90011.

Put this in the view:

```
<canvas id="graph" width="200" height="150"></canvas>
```

Javascript part:

```
// Send the drawn image to the server
$('#sendBtn').live('click', function () {
    var image = graph[0].toDataURL("image/png");
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Default.aspx/UploadImage',
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Image sent!');
        }
    });
});
```

Source code was taken from this blog article: [Send Canvas Content to Your Server](http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/send-canvas-content-to-server/)