# how can i make screen shot of html div which contains images, and text using php or javascript or jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to capture the particular div content and div contains images or text or anything?

if any possible ways with script please tell me.

Comment: We need a lot more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to 'screenshot' an element, but what you could do, is draw the  the div into a canvas element, then use the `HTMLCanvasElement` object's `toDataURL` function to get a `data:` URI with the image's contents.

as

```
var c = document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
/* then use the canvas 2D drawing functions to add text, etc. for the result */
```

When the user clicks "Capture", do this:

```
window.open('', document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id').toDataURL());
```

This will open a new tab or window with the 'screenshot', allowing the user to save it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @Rab Nawaz... its copy of answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript?rq=1  instead of this type of answers better to keep link... any way thanks for your response..