# Is it possible to make a picture of a specific part of your website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My apologies if this is a stupid question, but is there a way to 'take a picture' from a certain part of the website and save it on the computer?

**HTML**

```
<div id="red" color="red" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
<div id="green" color="green" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
<div id="blue" color="blue" width="100px" height="100px"></div>
```

For example I have a webpage with 3 divs next to each other and I want to take a picture of only the green div, and save it as a jpeg or something.

Is this at all possible with JQuery/Javascript for example?

Comment: which picture you want ? Back ground image of div or if the div has a `<img src='http://someting.com/some.img' />` ? Assuming that you always need `div id =green` image.

Comment: See this question 


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript

Comment: Depending your needs you could simply try a webcrawler to get the piece of code from a website. Here is a nice tutorial http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website/

Answer (score 2):

As [grigno](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18466785/2129835) said, [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) would be a good choice since it has [screen capture](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) capabilities.

Here's an example of how you can take pictures of a specific element using [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect).

#### JavaScript

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

address = 'https://stackoverflow.com/q/18466303/2129835';
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.clipRect = page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.querySelector('.question .post-text').getBoundingClientRect(); 
            });
            page.render('output.png');
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

#### Result: output.png

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this plays out, but you may be able to take advantage of the [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) element and [draw the `<div>` there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas). Then canvas has export options to convert to jpg, png, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is not easily done, but there are some projects which can help you out.
Have a look at:

- [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) - created by Stack Overflow user @niklas, see [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678156/782609) for more info.
- [jsFeedback](https://wiki.openmrs.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=34148944)

Basically, they use `<canvas>` to draw each DOM element on it, and then save it as bitmap. Due to this mechanics, the output image may not be 100% accurate though.

If you opt to use html2canvas, it accepts a list of DOM elements to render. Have a look at [this example](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/master/examples/demo.html#L8) for usage.

Other approach would be to create Chrome extension - it's easy then - if that's feasible in your use case. If so, have a look at [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab).

Answer (score 1):

I used [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) with [screen capture](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Screen-Capture) to take a picture of a site.
After saving the image on the web server you can cut the image file to get a specific area of your page.