# Is it possible to print screen of a flash animation from javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

Is it possible to save as a file (or binary data) what the user see in a flash animation when he clicks on an html button ?

For example, in a HTML page, I have a swf that will display a video, and a `<input />` button. When the user click on this input, a JavaScript code will be run to print what the user see in the flash animation (and only the flash animation, not the full screen or the full body) when he clicks on the button.

I'm wondering if this is possible ?

Note: I don't have access to the source code of the Flash animation, only a swf.

Comment: It can be useful: [How to take screen shot of a div with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need access to the swf