# HTML5 how to take a print screen on a particular div class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using html5 webpage i displayed some product list, this list are inside the div tag this is designed using css. i want to print the product list get the css style.

i need to click a button 
that button to capture and display the window particular div class or id.
then to print the div class or id

Comment: Are you limited to client side languages?

Comment: This[ link][1]  might help you to you matter


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div

Answer (score 9):

These links will give you a good idea of what you are looking for

[How to take screenshot of a div with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2012/04/taking-screenshots-using-xss-and-the-html5-canvas/

They all do it by using HTML Canvas, if you are new to it then here is a tutorial to help you out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Canvas_tutorial

There are other ways too. You can also do it by using a Javascript API

http://grabz.it/api/javascript/

or

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Hope it helped !