# Re-size every Element in HTML with jQuery or Canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

I have this script working http://makeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/ and I want to save the plate (image) 2 * current size. Now the car plate have 715x160px, and i need to save it at 715*2 px 160*2 px (1430x360) and keep the quality of images.

I'm using html2canvas to save current images, but is it possible to resize all elements at once?

this is the html code for 1 plate:

```
<div class="plate front car with-left-badge clearfix" id="front-plate">
<div class="bg diamond"></div>
<div class="border burgundy three" style="width: 627px; height: 142px; left: auto; right: 5px; display: block;"></div>
<div class="badge left" style="display: block;"><span><div class="fimg"><img alt="" src="images/badge/uk-ireland/euro-gb.png"></div></span></div>
<p class="text hiline" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 140px;"><span class="orange"><em class="char1">Y</em><em class="char2">O</em><em class="char3">U</em><em class="char4">R</em><em class="char5 space"> </em><em class="char6">R</em><em class="char7">E</em><em class="char8">G</em></span></p>
<div class="slogan" style="display: block;"><p style="left: 32.5px; right: auto;" class="CourierNew"><span class="red">www.makeaplateuk.com</span></p></div>
<div id="imageHolder_front_id" class="imageHolder_front"></div>
<p class="clone hiline" style="font-size: 140px;"><span class="orange"><em class="char1">Y</em><em class="char2">O</em><em class="char3">U</em><em class="char4">R</em><em class="char5 space"> </em><em class="char6">R</em><em class="char7">E</em><em class="char8">G</em></span></p></div>
```

and this is the result [image: http://makeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/cart/zzzzz-car-front-05-15-2014.png]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it as an image first using the suggestion in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript). Then, using PHP GD, manipulate image size to the desired resolution.

This [link](http://runnable.com/UnF-tFdudNt1AABt/how-to-resize-an-image-using-gd-library-for-php) might help you with PHP GD.

Comment: I can save the images, but as you can see the image now have 715x160px and I need it at 1430x320px. If I use php to resize it will pixelate the image

Comment: ok. then I suggest make an alternate classes for every div you got there. one is for 715x160px, the second is for the larger one.

say,

for the small one you give a div additional class of "outer-small" with this style: width: 627px; height: 142px;

if you want to make it larger execute a .removeClass("outer-small") and then .addClass("outer-big") where outer-big's style is width: 800px;

so summing it up, every div should have their equivalent class if they become bigger. you should provide styles for the bigger ones that will resemble the smaller one.

Comment: remake your canvas in x2 of it's size. then use those classes and toggle it with classes for the smaller one.