# Share a map generated using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a Google Map on my web page using Google Maps JavaScript API v3. It just has bunch of **markers** and **info windows** associated with them, nothing fancy. Now I want to:

1. Enable the user to share this **Google Map** (with markers and infoWindows) on social services like **Facebook/Twitter**
2. Enable the user to open this map (with markers and infoWindows) in www.google.com/maps... by clicking a "enlarge this map" button, like they're accustomed to with embedded Google maps.

Actually if I'm only able to achieve (2) and (1) is not possible from my website, then (1) can be achieved on www.google.com/maps.. anyway, so (2) is the critical point.

I've searched over the web for a decent amount of time but I couldn't find any leads.

P.S. I've tried to make this question more specific and have highlighted the specific parts for visual convenience as well.

### Update

I'm using following code to generate said Google map

```js
var latlng = [{
      title: 'Title 1',
      address: 'Address 1',
      city: 'City 1',
      postcode: 'Postcode 1',
      phone: 'Phone 1',
      lat: 43.7810795,
      lng: -79.3245521
    }, {
      title: 'Title 2',
      address: 'Address 2',
      city: 'City 2',
      postcode: 'Postcode 2',
      phone: 'Phone 2',
      lat: 43.7910795,
      lng: -79.3245521
    }
    /* the are many more objects like the two above ... */
  ],
  markers = [],
  infoWindows = [],
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function addMarker(info, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.lng),
    map: map,
    title: info.title,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  markers.push(marker);

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div class="infowindow"><h3>' + info.title + '</h3><div>' + info.address + '<br />' + info.phone + '</div></div>',
    maxWidth: 200
  });

  infoWindows.push(infoWindow);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    for (var k = 0; k < infoWindows.length; k++) {
      if (infoWindows[k] !== infoWindow) {
        infoWindows[k].close();
      }
    }
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}


function gmapInitialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: latlng[0].lat,
      lng: latlng[0].lng
    }
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector('#loc_map_14'), mapOptions);

  for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
    addMarker(latlng[i], map);
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  (function($) {
    var map_enlarge = $('.map-enlarge'),
      map_restore = $('.map-restore'),
      site_main = $('.site-main');
    map_restore.hide();

    map_enlarge.click(function() {
      site_main.addClass('sidebar-extended');
      $(this).closest('.locations-map-cntnr').css('height', 600);
      $(this).hide();
      map_restore.show();

      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

      map.fitBounds(bounds);

      return false;
    });

    map_restore.click(function() {
      site_main.removeClass('sidebar-extended');
      $(this).closest('.locations-map-cntnr').removeAttr('style');
      $(this).hide();
      map_enlarge.show();
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

      map.fitBounds(bounds);

      return false;
    });

  })(jQuery);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', gmapInitialize);
```

@MrUpsidown thanks for the comment, so the answer to (1) is "deliver this same map as the only content through a separate/dedicated URL of my website as well and then share that URL on social services". That's a good solution.

`Why would you want users to open the same map with maps.google.com?` My objective is to replace an embedded Google map with this map and keep the "Open in Google maps" option/button too so that they're seamlessly redirected to google.com and still see this map.

I think I'm going to look into creating a static map using Google map's API. Will look into that.

Comment: Downvoter and the delete request guy (most likely the same one)! care to leave a comment elaborating the _actual_ reason? Too broad? really? I want  my **google map** which has been generated on a **web page** using **javascript** shared on **facebook/twitter ...**. I've highlighted the specific parts of the question for convenience.

Comment: this map has **markers** and **info windows**, in case you missed these specific parts as well.

Comment: Definitely **too broad** to me as well. Your question is vague, contains no code and we don't know what you want to achieve. 1. Can't you build your own system to save information relative to your map (markers, infowindows, etc.) and be able to fetch it by a specific url? Also what do you want to share on social media (screenshot? url?) more info needed! 2. You are showing the map on your website. Why would you want users to open the same map with maps.google.com? I see no point doing that unless you can explain what you are trying to achieve. And in any case you can't.

Comment: Well for (1) just save your different markers in a database and create a logic to retrieve the markers, map center and zoom level (or the map bounds). Link that to a specific url for example: `example.com/map/id_of_saved_map` get that id on page load, and get the corresponding content from your db. If you are having an issue with that, you should let us know what you have tried and what issue(s) you are having with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For social sharing, you will need to encode the entirety of your maps configuration into the querystring. A mediocre version might look something like:

```
location.hash = '#' + JSON.stringify({ m:markers, i:infoWindows });
```

However, this would never work for Twitter given the imposed URL length restrictions. You could use a URL shortening service to shorten the ugly JSON URLs. Or, use a decent querystring builder, there are a multitude available on GitHub.

```
// at some point restore from the hash:
function restore() {
  var hash = location.hash.substring(1),
      json = hash && JSON.parse(hash);
  // do what you gotta do.
  json.m.forEach(addMarker);
  json.w.forEach(addWindow);
}
restore();  // on DOMContentLoaded or whatever

function share(markers, windows) {
  var url = location.href.replace(/#.*$/,'') + '#';
  // swap this for something less terrible:
  url += JSON.stringify({ m:markers, w:infoWindows });
  shorten(url, function(short) {
    window.open('//www.twitter.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(short));
  });
}

function shorten(url, callback) {
  // use what you know. example is http://github.com/synacorinc/jan
  http.get('https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN'+
    '&format=txt&longUrl='+encodeURIComponent(url),
    function(err, res, body) {
      callback(body);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks like promising. I'm going to give it a try shortly (hoping I'm not too late to give the bounty to best answer)

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you some ideas I had. You can take a screenshot of the div containing the map, and then share it on social services.

[**Here's how to take a screen shot with js**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript/6887206#6887206)

It seems that sharing a map on facebook is as easy as obtaining the map's url and posting it. Is there a way your map website could obtain the map's url?

Comment: obtaining the map URL is actually the point # 2 in my question. When one opens that map (by appending some query string variables probably, I don't know the API for that), the URL in the address bar is the URL of that map. Screenshot is not an option since I want a _living_ google map to be shard.

Answer (score 0):

There are some point that you need to consider.

1) Sharing your code via social media news some extra tweaking. First of all you to create a URL listener for your app. Then you can create custom map instances.

2) If you want to show some preview images you may use [Google Maps Image APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/)