# Convert a div to image without canvas

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need to generate an image with a corner ribbon, which musn't be an image since the text inside it changes. 
Once it's generated, I need the div (the image + the ribbon) to be saved as an image, but I'm not able to do it with html2canvas also because I don't have the images, I just have the link (and saving them would take too much time). Is there another method?

Comment: (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6p3hap19/)

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript) generated this [interesting fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FZkk/1/). I think that you could adapt this for your use.

It's essentually this javascript:

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```