# Take screen shot in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code that will take screenshot of my desktop and it is running fine on my local machine but as soon as i upload the file in the server it is not taking the screen shot and throwing a error.

Error: The handle is invalid

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is
>   invalid    at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX,
>   Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size
>   blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)    at
>   Main.Capture(String CapturedFilePath)
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is
>   invalid    at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX,
>   Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size
>   blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)    at
>   Main.Capture(String CapturedFilePath)
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is
>   invalid    at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX,
>   Int32 sourceY, Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size
>   blockRegionSize, CopyPixelOperation copyPixelOperation)    at
>   System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY,
>   Int32 destinationX, Int32 destinationY, Size blockRegionSize)    at
>   Main.Capture(String CapturedFilePath)

My Asp.net Code behind code is as follows:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(2700, 800);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as  System.Drawing.Image);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(25, 25, 25, 25, bitmap.Size);
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    //  bitmap.Save(@"d:\\Screen", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    Ret = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You can refer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to take screenshot of user's desktop - it is not possible from C# (i.e. server side).

If you are trying to take a screenshot of a server - it kinda makes no sense. It doesn't work for you since there could be no desktop at all on the server: ASP.NET is hosted by IIS which is logged in as a service and thus doesn't have access to server's desktop.

Comment: okay..so this is not possible in asp.net. so to achieve this thing we need to have a desktop application..right??

Comment: You could try to use some client-side technology like Java applets or Adobe Flash, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: ok torvin..thanks for your suggestion :) and it was really helpfull.