# How to save or download image after witing some text on it in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my current project I want to print some text on image and after editing it save/print that image using PHP or javascript or jquery. The image is blank cheque like here I attach.

I used the text box for write cheque details on a cheque, cheque details like input payee name, account no, amount, an amount in a word.

So, can you please help me for solving this query.

[image: cheque details]

Comment: How are you using text box for writing cheque details on the cheque?

Comment: Short answer, use css canvas to do it. Check for details by yourself

Comment: What have you tried so far? Posting your current code will help us offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way here to do is to take a kind-of screenshot of your cheque using javascript/jquery if the text overlayed like you have in the input boxes. (Maybe remove the box-borders to make it more realistic)
Have a look this: [Webpage screenshot](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/08/take-webpage-screenshot-html5-jquery-javascript.html) and [how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-with-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-with-javascript).

To do it using php, you'll need to use the [imagettftest](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) function. [This link](http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-gd-library-adding-text-writing.php) might help.

Comment: screenshot is not solution for this, because I need final image without text box, just need text of that textbox in n image.

Comment: Thats why I said "Maybe remove the box-borders to make it more realistic". If still you think screenshot isn't the way to go, try my other example for server side placing text on image using `imagettftest` function.

Comment: Thnks gaganshera.

Comment: @tejalkaretha if the answer helped you could you please mark it as correct / upvote it?