# Convert div into image without canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-5, html5-canvas

I want to convert a div (in which I have headings, form, buttons etc.) into image. How can I do it without using Canvas? Is there any best solution for me? I preferred solution in JQuery or JS. I am using Laravel 5.2 in this project.

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-with-javascript

Comment: The real question is why?