# How to generate a png with gitgraph.js

Tags: javascript, git

I would like to use [GitGraph.js](https://gitgraphjs.com) to generate some nice looking graphs for documentation of workflows. Therefor I need these graphs as png files.

My first attempt was to create a static html page, load the gitgraph.js, create the graph, load it browser and take a screenshot to save the result as png.

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@gitgraph/js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="graph-container"></div>
  <script>
    const graphContainer = document.getElementById("graph-container");
    const gitgraph = GitgraphJS.createGitgraph(graphContainer);
    const master = gitgraph.branch("master");
    master.commit("Initial commit");
    master.commit("Second commit");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just to get the graph:

[image: nice looking git graph]

As these steps are painful work for more than one picture, I would like to do it automatically.
In my dreams I have a file for each picture containing only the javascript code, e.g. `graph_A.js`:

```js
const gitgraph = GitgraphJS.createGitgraph(graphContainer);
const master = gitgraph.branch("master");
master.commit("Initial commit");
master.commit("Second commit");
```

Next step is to call a batch script, press a button or execute a command in my favorite IDE (*in this case Visual Studio Code*) and after a few seconds I have a `graph_A.png` with the result as shown above.

As I'm new to javascript can you give me some hints how to solve my problem? Any advice what kind of toolchain I can use?

Thank you very much in advance from a low level embedded C programmer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

That was requested in [nicoespeon/gitgraph.js issue 183](https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/issues/183) (2018) and again with [issue 375](https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js/issues/375) (2020).

But this is outside the scope of the [`nicoespeon/gitgraph.js`](https://github.com/nicoespeon/gitgraph.js) library, so you will have to include a third party screenshot utility like [html2canvas used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585298/6309).